# Delete method in Doubly Linked List when implementing graphs as an adjacency list

Tags: java, data-structures, graph, adjacency-list

I have been trying to implement simple graphs (Directed/Undirected+Weighted/Unweighted) as an adjacency list as a part of my data structures course project, and I couldn't get the delete method to work except if I used instanceof for every type(Vertex, Edge, and GraphNode). I have equals method implemented in every class, but the delete method does not call them by default, I have to down cast before doing that. Here is the code for this method:

```
public void delete(T data)
{
    if(!isEmpty())
    {
        if(data instanceof Edge)
        {
            Edge edge = (Edge)data;
            Node<T> temp = head;
            while(temp != null)
            {
                if(edge.equals((Edge)head.data))
                {
                    deleteHead();
                    return;
                }   
                else if(edge.equals((Edge)tail.data))
                {
                    deleteTail();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    while(temp != null)
                    {   
                        if(edge.equals((Edge)temp.data))
                        {
                            (temp.previous).next = temp.next;
                            (temp.next).previous = temp.previous;
                            return;
                        }
                        temp = temp.next;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(data instanceof Vertex)
        {
            Vertex vertex = (Vertex)data;
            Node<T> temp = head;
            while(temp != null)
            {
                if(vertex.equals((Vertex)head.data))
                {
                    deleteHead();
                    return;
                }   
                else if(vertex.equals((Vertex)tail.data))
                {
                    deleteTail();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    while(temp != null)
                    {   
                        if(vertex.equals((Vertex)temp.data))
                        {
                            (temp.previous).next = temp.next;
                            (temp.next).previous = temp.previous;
                            return;
                        }
                        temp = temp.next;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(data instanceof GraphNode)
        {
            GraphNode gn = (GraphNode)data;
            Node<T> temp = head;
            while(temp != null)
            {
                if(gn.equals((GraphNode)head.data))
                {
                    deleteHead();
                    return;
                }   
                else if(gn.equals((GraphNode)tail.data))
                {
                    deleteTail();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    while(temp != null)
                    {   
                        if(gn.equals((GraphNode)temp.data))
                        {
                            (temp.previous).next = temp.next;
                            (temp.next).previous = temp.previous;
                            return;
                        }
                        temp = temp.next;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(data.equals(head.data))
        {
            deleteHead();
            return;
        }   
        else if(data.equals(tail.data))
        {
            deleteTail();
            return;
        }
        Node<T> current = head;
        while(current != null)
        {   
            if(current.data.equals(data))
            {
                current = current.next;
                current.previous = current;
                return;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
        throw new NodeDoesNotExistException();
    }
    else 
        throw new EmptyListException();
}
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear what is being asked; do you want to get rid of the two cases which examine the type of the argument? Is `T` a template parameter? Please provide a bit more context.

Comment: (If you're looking to have your **working** code reviewed / improved, this question would probably be better suited on [codereview.se].)

Comment: I want to get of all of the if statements with the instanceof if possible. T is a generic parameter.